# What is the difference between Spark Client and Spark Driver?

Tags: apache-spark

What is the difference between Spark Client and Spark Driver? I keep hearing that Spark Client is the one that does spark-submit but I never had to do that all I do is install Spark Libraries and Initialize spark context under `public static void main(String[] args)` like the code below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class JavaWordCount {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create Spark context with Spark configuration
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(new SparkConf()
                         .setAppName("Spark Count"))
                         .setMaster(master_url)
                         .setJars(JavaSparkContext.jarOfClass(JavaWordCount.class));

    // get threshold
    final int threshold = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

    // read in text file and split each document into words
    JavaRDD<String> tokenized = sc.textFile(args[0]).flatMap(
      new FlatMapFunction() {
        public Iterable call(String s) {
          return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
        }
      }
    );

    // count the occurrence of each word
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = tokenized.mapToPair(
      new PairFunction() {
        public Tuple2 call(String s) {
          return new Tuple2(s, 1);
        }
      }
    ).reduceByKey(
      new Function2() {
        public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
          return i1 + i2;
        }
      }
    );

    // filter out words with fewer than threshold occurrences
    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> filtered = counts.filter(
      new Function, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call(Tuple2 tup) {
          return tup._2 >= threshold;
        }
      }
    );

    // count characters    
    JavaPairRDD<Character, Integer> charCounts = filtered.flatMap(
      new FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Integer>, Character>() {
        @Override
        public Iterable<Character> call(Tuple2<String, Integer> s) {
          Collection<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>(s._1().length());
          for (char c : s._1().toCharArray()) {
            chars.add(c);
          }
          return chars;
        }
      }
    ).mapToPair(
      new PairFunction<Character, Character, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Character, Integer> call(Character c) {
          return new Tuple2<Character, Integer>(c, 1);
        }
      }
    ).reduceByKey(
      new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
          return i1 + i2;
        }
      }
    );

    System.out.println(charCounts.collect());
  }
}
```

In this code I dont see any spark-submit so which is the client and which is the driver here? Also I dont really understand what is happening with SparkConf.setJars? Why is that needed and what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Master is the one who creates the Task and submits it to the Workers and coordinates between different Job Stages,whereas the Driver sits one step above the Master which is involved in creating the context and creating the RDD Graph,which it then submits to the Master.

The Spark Driver is a program that declares Transformations and actions on RDDs of data and submits such requests to the master.It basically creates your SparkContext.

Hence,the Driver prepares the context and "Declares" operations on data using RDD Transformations and Actions.The Driver then submits this serialized RDD graph to the Master.
The Master then creates the Task out of it and submit them to the Worker for the execution.It also coordinates different Job stages.

Answer (score 0):

By Spark Client I'm assuming you're talking about *Spark Master*, which is the server responsible for scheduling Spark jobs.

The code you have works with the Spark API, but you have to run it, as you run any program. In order to run jobs in Spark, you have to schedule them with the relevant resource manager (Standalone, YARN or Mesos) to actually execute the job in the cluster environment.

After you assemble your JAR, you go to the Spark Master server and schedule the job using the `spark-submit` script. [As the documentation states](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html):

> Once a user application is bundled, it can be launched using the
>   bin/spark-submit script. This script takes care of setting up the
>   classpath with Spark and its dependencies, and can support different
>   cluster managers and deploy modes that Spark supports:

```
./bin/spark-submit \
  --class <main-class> \
  --master <master-url> \
  --deploy-mode <deploy-mode> \
  --conf <key>=<value> \
  ... # other options
  <application-jar> \
  [application-arguments]
```

> Some of the commonly used options are:
>
> - --class: The entry point for your application (e.g. org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi)
> - --master: The master URL for the cluster (e.g. spark://23.195.26.187:7077)
> - --deploy-mode: Whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes (cluster) or locally as an external client (client) (default: client)
>     †
> - --conf: Arbitrary Spark configuration property in key=value format. For values that contain spaces wrap “key=value” in quotes (as shown).
>     application-jar: Path to a bundled jar including your application and
>     all dependencies. The URL must be globally visible inside of your
>     cluster, for instance, an hdfs:// path or a file:// path that is
>     present on all nodes. application-arguments: Arguments passed to the
>     main method of your main class, if any

---

> Also I dont really understand what is happening with
>   SparkContext.setJars? Why is that needed and what does it do?

I assume you mean `SparkConf.setJars`. What that settings helps do is distribute JARs which aren't packaged into an uber JAR to the worker nodes, if needed. This is identical to passing the `--jars` flag to `spark-submit`.

Comment: Hi! By Client I don't mean master. I see master and workers as separate entities. Apart from that I keep hearing the word "client" which I dont know what it is. Also I don't go to Spark Master and run spark-submit. as stated in my question I never had to run invoke spark-submit script. I just set SparkConf.setMaster(ip) and invoke the main() function of my program thats it. I don't manually invoke spark-submit script anywhere

Comment: When I invoke the main program of the above code wouldn't that run as a Job? Assume I am using standalone mode

Comment: @user1870400 You're executing the job via your IDE. It's queuing the job on your behalf to the Spark Master, similar to the way you'd externally call `spark-submit`. But when you run in a production environment, there's no IDE, you schedule via the submit script.